Log4j2 with multiple appenders not writing to console
I have a log4j2.XML as below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%date %-5level %logger - %msg"/>
        </Console>

        <Kafka name="KafkaAppender" topic="cdf-databricks-log">
            <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:JsonLayout.json">
                <EventTemplateAdditionalField key="info" format="JSON" value='{"$resolver": "map"}' />
            </JsonTemplateLayout>
            <Property name="bootstrap.servers">${env:KAFKA_HOST}:${env:KAFKA_PORT}</Property>
            <Property name="security.protocol">SASL_SSL</Property>
            <Property name="sasl.mechanism">PLAIN</Property>
            <Property name="sasl.jaas.config">org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required  username="${env:KAFKA_USER}" password="${env:KAFKA_PASSWD}";</Property>
        </Kafka>
        <Async name="AsyncAppender">
            <AppenderRef ref="KafkaAppender"/>
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root>
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" level="ALL"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="KafkaAppender" level="INFO"/>
        </Root>
        <!-- Do not let org.apache.kafka log to a Kafka appender on DEBUG level. That will cause recursive logging -->
        <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="WARN" />
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

I want all the logs to be directed to Console an only the INFO logs to be directed to Kafka.
When I use the application, I do not see the logs being written to the console.
I have found that writing dedicated logger nodes based on class/ package name like below works. But I have a requirement to make this Log4j2.xml a reusable component and that's why I do not want an individual class name present here.
        <Logger name="com.abc.xxx.Someclassname" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="KafkaAppender"/>
        </Logger

Any suggestions where I am going wrong in the first log4j2.xml?

You didn't specify the level of the root logger, so the default ERROR applies and your configuration is equivalent to:
<Root level="ERROR">
    <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" level="ALL"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="KafkaAppender" level="INFO"/>
</Root>

In order to be logged a message must by at least as specific as the level of the configured logger and the level of the appender references (cf. filtering). For example if logs from a com.example logger must have a level of ERROR or higher in order to end up in Kafka (level of logger: ERROR, level of appender reference: INFO). Log events from the org.apache.kafka appender only need a level of WARN (level of logger: WARN, level of appender references inherited from the root logger: INFO).
Changing the level of the root logger should solve your problem.
